# Get sick in China with no identity

Tags: health, china, identity-cards

Say you are in China, a country where you have to pay for health care. What happens if you are traveling and you become unconscious and you have no form of identification on you. Would they leave you to die?

Comment: Although interesting, I am not sure this question is answerable according to the SE format.

Comment: Far too broad. Depends massively on the country, and where you are found etc.

Comment: Not sure I'd agree with the "too broad" votes, since the example of China is given.

Comment: Why is this too broad? The question is quite straight-forwad. What happens if you are seriously ill in China and don't have any identification with you? Will hospitals take care of you or will you be on your own?

Comment: If you are found near no-go zone wherever in the world and people are really desperate, you can be "unexpected heap of resources". Same time you can be found by carefull person, who will take care of you. Wherever you are. There is also a nonzero chance you will be hit by meteorite or toilet seat from space station while unconcious...

Comment: If the question were restricted only to China, maybe it wouldn't be "too broad," but if China is just an example, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: The amount of money you pay for health care in China is pretty nominal even by Chinese standards, so I imagine not having funds immediately available would not be a factor in whatever care you might get at the hands of strangers. You might have more of an issue in, say, the US.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Despite what fretful European newspaper editors might assume, people are not dying in the streets in America for lack of health insurance. Rather, the problem is that hospitals are obligated (legally as well as morally) to give emergency care to all, ao the poor end up getting treatment in the most expensive way to receive it, and the cost of caring for the indigent is passed on to those with insurance, which then becomes stratospherically expensive. The idea that a public hospital would leave someone bleeding out in the street for lack of funds is an invention of TV.

Comment: @Choster So those stories of ambulances passing hospital after hospital to find one that will accept the indigent are not real? I am pretty sure it's not a common situation, but does it happen? I'm aware of the factors you mention and how it typically works with a poor person who gets a stroke or heart attack.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Hospitals fill up. If you read American tabloids, you'd think half the babies in Canada or the UK are birthed in the street, from the horror stories of ambulances being sent all over town. The difference of course is the blame is placed, equally unfairly, on oppressive government monopoly instead of greedy insurance companies. But I doubt they're in reality being turned away on monetary grounds. An EMT isn't going to rifle your unconscious body looking for an insurance card before radioing for a bed.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If someone is having a medical emergency, such as a stroke or heart attack, in the US, a hospital has to at least get them stable, regardless of their ability to pay. If the ambulance is passing hospital after hospital, it should be for some other reason (such as another hospital being full). If it does happen, you can report it to the government and they will investigate, and the penalties for the hospital are quite serious.

Comment: USA has a law called EMTALA which prohibits denying treatment if the condition is serious enough.  But if it's not serious, or you are "stabilized," a for-profit hospital will likely get rid of you as fast as they can.  Consequently, the uninsured make the non-profit E.R. their "family doctor."

Comment: Did close-voters misread this? It's particularly about China. It doesn't say "Cina **or another** country where you have to pay. It simply says China. Why is this too broad? Please read and think before you vote to close.

Comment: Is China infamous for not treating those serously sick people? I have never heard about it.

Answer (score 8):

Keep in mind, this is purely anecdotal.

A few months back I went to China with a small group for an exchange program at my university. We (students) would teach some classes at a university there. One of the other students got seriously ill and had to be taken to hospital. He needed treatment immediately. He didn't have his insurance on him or it could not be verified at that time. They refused to treat him until they had money in hand. Our university decided to front the bill of 6000 euro and got that back from his insurance later.

Bottom line, it doesn't matter who you are, as long as you have money or friends with money.

Comment: @Fiksdal, so in the USA I would left on the road and not even taken to the hospital....

Comment: @Fiksdal, no but it is one of the reasons I would rather not go on holiday to the USA.  The risk of going somewhere where most people thinks providing healthcare without payment at the time of care is evil socialism just puts me off.

Comment: @Fiksdal but what if they can't find my insurance paperwork while I am dying...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47642/discussion-between-fiksdal-and-ian-ringrose). @IanRingrose

Comment: In the USA, at least, if someone can get you to the ER then hospitals are required to treat you, regardless of your ability to pay. That's why ERs get so darn full, because low-income families can't get reasonable medical treatment, so they wait until it becomes an emergency and go to the ER.